# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MH_CRUD_Model.Member>'

Tags: c#, api, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to display all the data of Member by merging First name and Last name to Name.
The function is successful. But it starts to give me error when I try to write the select function like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Members")]
    public IQueryable<Member> GetMembers()
    {
        var member = db.Members.Select(m=>
            new{
                Name = m.LastName +" "+ m.LastName,
                m.Title,
                m.ProjectId
            });
        return member.ToList();

    }
```

any Help

Comment: You returning new unknown(anonymous) type with `new {}` and result expects to be of `Member` type

Comment: Either change your function's return type to `List` or remove `.ToList()` from your return.

Comment: I did all what you said and also different kinds of errors based on the returned value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an `anonymous` type in your select statement without specifying any type. At the same time, your function return type is `IQueryable<Member>` and at the end of your function you are returning list of `anonymous` `object` type. You need to match the function return type and return data. Here is my solution

First create a model class for return data like named `MemberReturn` you can use name as your choice

```
class MemberReturn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

}
```

Then select data in linq query as `MemberReturn` type and change your function's return type as `List<MemberReturn>`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Members")]
public List<MemberReturn> GetMembers()
{
    var member = db.Members.Select(m=>
            new MemberReturn {
                Name = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
                Title = m.Title,
                ProjectId = m.ProjectId
            });
    return member.ToList();

}
```

Comment: I did as your answer but I got an error 

"'MH_CRUD_Model.Member' does not contain a definition for 'Name'"

Comment: public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //FK Field 
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        //Member name field 
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        //Title field
        public string Title { get; set; }
  
        //Navigation Property
        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Mai check out updated code, hope this time will work, if face problem let me know that

Comment: great, happy coding :)